# Converting 3-2-1 cake to be baked in the oven

Tags: baking, cake

I made two containers of 3-2-1 cake and forgot about them.  I'd like to make cakes out of them (or at least attempt to).  Is it as simple as following the angel food cake recipe and baking in a 9X13 pan?  That way the worst that will happen is I waste some water (since that's all the angel food cake calls for).

Edit: 3-2-1 cake is where you take 1/2 a boxed cake (any flavor) and 1/2 a boxed angel food cake and mix the two together.  Then you use 3 tbsp of the cake mix, 2 tbsp water, and microwave for 1 minute.

Comment: What is "3-2-1 cake"?

Comment: What ingredients does the boxed cake mix call for?

Comment: The angel food cake just calls for water.  The cake mix calls for eggs, oil, and water.  The 3-2-1 recipe works well because the angel food cake mix has eggs already in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

If you can microwave a cake mix you can bake it in an oven. These mixes are made to be baked, so just follow the directions on the box for baking times as a guide and adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've made several "microsponges" using a conventional spongecake recipe cooked in little disposable cups in the microwave as a dessert for my kids. There's no chemical leavener in the recipe, just meringue and pate de bombe and a bit of flour folded together. The microwave hyperaerates this mix almost as fluffy as angel food cake. I personally can't eat boxed angel food cake - the chemical leavener/emulsifier is unpalatable.

I question your understanding that a 3-2-1 mix works because the contribution of angel cake. Angel food cake is purely egg white, whereas egg yolk gives flavor and richness. I would think reincorporating egg yolks expected in the original boxed cake would improve taste and texture. Otherwise, I imagine the taste would resemble fluffy sweet baked flour. But as others mentioned, try it, experiment.